# Error with build.xml and ant

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors

Every time I try to launch a target in my `build.xml`, I receive an error. This is the relevant part of my `build.xml`.

```xml
<!-- init -->
<target name="init" description="Inizializza lo script Ant">
    <echo message="====== INIZIO TARGET INIT PER: ${target} ..." />
    <tstamp/>
    <loadproperties srcFile="buildfiles/build.properties"/> <!-- Line 83 -->
    <!-- Controllo che se non viene passato nessun parametro target lo imposto
     ad un valore di default che corrisponde alla variabile default_target presente
     nel build.properties-->
    <condition property="target" value="${default_target}">
        <not>
            <isset property="target"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
    <echo message="target init dopo il test " />
    <!--contiene prop. specifiche per l'ambiente ${target} -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="buildfiles/${target}.properties" />

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/${target}"/>  <!-- contiene il tar -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}/archives"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}/archives/${target}"/> <!-- contiene il jar-->
    <property environment="env"/>

    <echo message="***********************************" />
    <echo message="Il pacchetto sara' creato per : ${target}" />
    <echo message="JDK: ${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
    <echo message="***********************************" />
</target>
```

This is the error in the Eclipse console:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\amministratore\workspace_csi\servfci\build.xml:83: Unable to load file: sun.io.MalformedInputException
```

I use java JDK 131.06. How do I fix my `build.xml`?

Comment: try and use a really simple build.xml and then addd more stuff. This should help you narrow down what is wrong. From your error it looks like line 83 is wrong. What is line 83 in your file?

Comment: Opsss i forgot....

this :
<loadproperties srcFile="buildfiles/build.properties"/>

tnx for answer

now i try the simple build.xml

Comment: Could you please post more information about the error? I mean, is there more lines after `BUILD FAILED C:\Users\amministratore\workspace_csi\servfci\build.xml:83: Unable to load file: sun.io.MalformedInputException`? This seems to be a encoding problem.

Comment: You are using JDK 1.3.1_06 ? That should be forbidden.